# How to make marquee content appear right side of the browser as soon as it exits the left side?

Tags: javascript, marquee

I have a marquee where currently the content exits left side of browser and appears again on the right side of the browser once all the content has passed out of the left side

How can I make the content reappear on the right side of the browser the second it exits out of the left?

```
<div class='marquee'>
  <div class='marquee-text'>
  Testing this marquee function <span>Testing this marquee function</span> <span>Testing this marquee function</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.marquee {
  white-space: no-wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.marquee > div.marquee-text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
}

span {
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

JS

```
var marquee = $('div.marquee');
var go = true;

marquee.hover(
  function() {
   go = false;
},
  function() {
   go = true;
  }
);

marquee.each(function() {
  var mar = $(this),
   indent = mar.width();
mar.marquee = function() {
  if (go) {
   indent--;
  mar.css('text-indent', indent);
  if (indent < -1 * mar.children('div.marquee-text').width()) {
    indent = mar.width();
    }
  };
}
mar.data('interval', setInterval(mar.marquee, 100 / 60));
});
console.log(marquee);
```

Comment: Create a clone of the marquee, detect when the first marquee is at left = 0, then push that other marquee forward. There will be a big problem if the marquee is wider than the viewport's width, though.

Comment: Could you possibly show me an example?